# ARM NEON aarch64: How to compare and update neon registers in optimized way?

Tags: c++, assembly, neon, arm64

Actually I am trying to figure out a good way to compare neon register values loaded from "*unsigned short*" array. As I'm working with a large project it's not possible to explain sharing the whole code portion. Rather I am going to share a similar example so that everyone can understand the actual problem scenario.

---

**C++ Implementation:**

```
unsigned short *values = new unsigned short[8];
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    if(values[i] > 255){
            values[i] = 255;
    }
}
```

---

**Assembly Implementation:**

```
MOV W3, #255
UMOV W2, V4.H[0]
CMP W2, #0x00FF
CSEL W2,W3, W2, GT
MOV V4.H[0], W2

UMOV W2, V4.H[1]
CMP W2, #0x00FF
CSEL W2,W3, W2, GT
MOV V4.H[1], W2

UMOV W2, V4.H[2]
CMP W2, #0x00FF
CSEL W2,W3, W2, GT
MOV V4.H[2], W2

UMOV W2, V4.H[3]
CMP W2, #0x00FF
CSEL W2,W3, W2, GT
MOV V4.H[3], W2

UMOV W2, V4.H[4]
CMP W2, #0x00FF
CSEL W2,W3, W2, GT
MOV V4.H[4], W2

UMOV W2, V4.H[5]
CMP W2, #0x00FF
CSEL W2,W3, W2, GT
MOV V4.H[5], W2

UMOV W2, V4.H[6]
CMP W2, #0x00FF
CSEL W2,W3, W2, GT
MOV V4.H[6], W2

UMOV W2, V4.H[7]
CMP W2, #0x00FF
CSEL W2,W3, W2, GT
MOV V4.H[7], W2
```

---

I know this is a bad assembly implementation for this scenario. Is it possible to **perform this task with fewer instructions**? I didn't find much assembly documentations regarding this compare and update instruction.
**Any good idea will be highly appreciated.** Thank you.

Comment: How about the `UMIN` instruction?

Comment: @Jester, Is there any link available that is providing example of UMIN instruction?

Comment: Shouldn't be more difficult than loading `v0` with your input, `v1` with all 255 values and then doing `umin v0.8h, v0.8h, v1.8h`

Comment: @Jester... Thanks a lot, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: `UMIN` is definitely THE most efficient solution. BTW, you should avoid moving values from SIMD registers to integer ones at all costs. It will cause a total pipeline flush costing you roughly 14 cycles each.

Comment: `new unsigned short[8];`  What the heck?  You know you're using C++, right?  You don't need to dynamically allocate storage for a single 16-byte array, just make it a local with automatic storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, you can use UMIN, or [VMIN](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489h/CIHDEEBE.html) in 32bit neon. [Sample implementation using neon](https://godbolt.org/g/DnRJf4) intrinsics which works for 32 and 64 bit neon:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arm_neon.h>

void clamp8(uint16_t values[8])
{
    uint16x8_t v = vld1q_u16(values);
    uint16x8_t x255 = vdupq_n_u16(255);
    uint16x8_t clamped = vminq_u16(v, x255);
    vst1q_u16(values, clamped);
}
```

This produces this arm64 neon code:

```
ldr q0, [x0]
movi v1.2d, #0xff00ff00ff00ff
umin v0.8h, v0.8h, v1.8h
str q0, [x0]
```